# I have a problem while my excel is writing, I can not stop the execution

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a situation here, I have a program which the exit is an excel file, that is Ok, but sometimes I have a big Excel file to write and in some situations I need to stop the program and kill that process to another hour do it again. But once I start the process to write, I can only stop when I stop using my Visual Studio, it's important to know that I am using a Form Application, I tried to create a Button that works when it's not running the process.

Looks like my Form is not accessible while the process is running.

Can anyone help me with this situation?

Comment: As you said, form is not responding while the process is running. When you call a long running method from the button clickhandler, it is blocked by this method. For long running tasks you may use [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Backgroundworker is in past. OP should use Tasks.

Comment: It would be better if you showed some of the code that you are using to write the Excel file.  I suspect that the reason it is taking a long time to complete is that you are writing every single cell individually versus writing out blocks of data.  Doing the work on a secondary thread may still be required, but the code can be structured to check for a cancellation request and exit gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

When you create Excel application, you effectively create a new process EXCEL.EXE. You can find it in Task Manager on Processes tab (in Apps section). You can stop action only by killing the Excel process - there's no other way around.

In order to free you UI thread, you should run Excel manipulation on another thread. The  [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) is perfect candidate for this. Since Excel is unmanaged code, you need to release **all** the references to its objects. This means that every property, every object used in your code must be released. But...this can be not enough. The thing is that EXCEL.EXE process *can potentially be still in Processes list* - you can see it *Background processes* section. In some cases the process can be gone.

To summarize what I've said, here's the basic skeleton you need:

1) Create procedure which works with Excel, wrap it in Task and run it.

2) Create separate procedure which can be called by another button to stop
    Excel process. This procedure also handles a case when quitting was successful.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // Hold reference to Excel
        private Process xlProc = null;

        private void OnRun(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Create new instance of EXCEL.EXE
                var xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };

                // Get Excel proccess in order to kill it
                var handle = new IntPtr(xlApp.Hwnd);
                xlProc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle == handle).First();

                // Create new workbook
                var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
                var xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

                // Do some operation
                xlSheet.Cells[1].Value = "Hello from .NET!";

                // Quit
                xlBook.Close(SaveChanges: false);
                xlApp.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet);

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

                KillExcel();

            });
        }

        // Kill Excel process if it still exists
        private void KillExcel()
        {
            if (!xlProc.HasExited)
            {
                xlProc.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```